# Linux Kali - internet connected but doesn't work without vpn or tor

Tags: linux, wifi, kali-linux, vpn, internet

I couldn't find an answer to this problem nor could I fix it myself. I am triple booting Ubuntu/Kali/Windows 11. The internet works completely fine on Ubuntu and Windows but when it comes to Kali Linux, I can't use the internet even though wifi is connected.

the command `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` successfully runs but when I ping a website (e.g. google.com), it returns `ping: www.google.com: Name or service not known`. When I turn on the VPN or use the tor browser, the internet is accessible. But if I just use firefox, it doesn't connect

When I turn on the VPN, I can ping `www.google.com`, otherwise I can't.

my **/etc/resolv.conf** file:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

when I run the command (as root): `for t in filter nat mangle raw security; do echo "Table '$t'" ; iptables -t "$t" -nvL 2>/dev/null; echo; done`. I get:

```
Table 'filter'
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Table 'nat'
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Table 'mangle'
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Table 'raw'
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Table 'security'
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

When I run the command `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf`, I get:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
```

Comment: So your computer is directly connected to the internet, without an ISP router? 127.0.0.1 is [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). If you ping that IP your PC is the one responding, not your router.

Comment: @roaima It worked! I changed that line into ```hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the command `grep hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf` gives this entry:

> ```
> hosts:  files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns myhostname
> ```

The `[!UNAVAIL=return]` looks suspect; it says that if the hot name/address lookup service isn't unavailable then return. But unfortunately it's before a lookup using DNS.

Carefully try removing that, so the line becomes as follows:

```
hosts:  files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```